# Modified closure and setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I have this little snippet (this is inside of an object):

```
var tout = 0;
self.initialize = function() {
    for (var key in periods) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.server.sendData('customData', periods[key], 0);
        }, tout);
        tout = tout + 7000;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm iterating through `periods` object fields, and I need each key to be visible inside my `setTimeout()` separately. Currently, that is not possible. I was trying something like this, hoping for a miracle:

```
self.initialize = function() {
    for (var key in periods) {
        var localkey = key; //here is the change
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.server.sendData('customData', periods[localkey], 0);
        }, tout);
        tout = tout + 7000;
    }
}
```

But obviously, a miracle did not happen. Does anyone have any idea on how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.initialize = function() {
    for (var key in periods) {
        (function(key) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                self.server.sendData('customData', periods[key], 0);
            }, tout);
            tout = tout + 7000;
        })(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just... Wow. That works. Thank you, this is something new to me. Could you explain a little bit?

Comment: It's using an [immediately invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to create a new scope, passing your variable as a parameter.  Inside the function, it's a separate variable so doesn't change as the loop progresses.